# html5 pattern for restricting a number

Tags: jquery, css, html

In this field we can enter 10 digit mobile number.

```
<input type="text" id="mnumber" placeholder="Mobile number:"
       title="Mobile Number" pattern="[0-9]{10}" required>
```

But i need to disallow users to enter `9999999999` number also. Is it possible using html5 pattern?

Comment: Do you want to disallow the number 9999999999?

Comment: According to MDN, the value for `pattern` should be a JavaScript-style regex: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/Input#attr-pattern. Perhaps see if you can write a regex to disallow `9999999999`?

Comment: If you are using HTML5 novelties for reading a phone number, why not use `type=tel`, which is designed for such purposes, instead of your own attempt at pattern matching?

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela indeed I would suggest type=tel too since it will show a (mostly) numbers keypad not the letters, but not the type=number one either, on touch devices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```html
<input type="text" 
       id="mnumber" 
       placeholder="Mobile number:" 
       title="Mobile Number" 
       pattern="(?![9]{10})[0-9]{10}"
       required>
```

Comment: Using the type=tel makes touch/mobile devices present a (mostly) numbers keypad, type=text shows the regular one.

Answer (score 1):

In your regular expression, use a look-ahead assertion.

```
(?!9999999999)\d{10}
```

Answer (score 0):

Html5 restrict number input

```
<form>
<input type="text" pattern="[^0-9]+" title="Numbers are not allowed">
<input type="submit">
</form>
```